# Exporting schema from oracle database is breaking views

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, expdp, oracle-dump

I am exporting with expdp a schema from a database and the process finishes with no error but when I try to use impdp to import the schema, several views fail to be imported with the following message:

> ORA-39083: Object type VIEW failed to create with error:
>
> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
>
> Failing sql is:
>
> CREATE  FORCE VIEW...

The create statement that is in the message effectively is missing the SELECT statement, because is truncated way before it should appear. When I check the VIEW in the source database the view is properly created.
The only possible cause I can see for this issue is the length of the statement given that all failing statements have between 389 characters and 404 characters at the point where the statements are truncated.

Is there a way to set the maximum number of characters that the expdp should be able to handle? Or is there a different way I which I should handle these views.